# image as tooltip using dojo

Tags: dojo, tooltip

I'm trying to display an image on mouseover of another image. I'm using dijit/Tooltip for that. Problem is, the image is not displaying on the first mouseover, it always appears on the second time onwards.  The images are dynamically displayed and have given a dynamic id.

```
<c:forEach items="${model.images}" var="image" varStatus="status">
    <img  src="${image.url}" height="50" onmouseover="showImage('${image.id}')" id="image${image.id}" /> 
<c:forEach>

<script>
    function showImage(name) {
        require(["dijit/Tooltip", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Tooltip){
            new Tooltip({
                connectId: ["image"+name],
                label: "<img src='/images/"+name+"'/>"
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dijit/Tooltip there is no need for an onmouseover function. With your code the first mouseover only sets up the Tooltip. The second time the Tooltip is attached and so it is displayed (and showImage() runs again, which isn't optimal).
You need to create the Tooltip when the image is added to the dom. You can refer to the [dijit/Tooltip guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tooltip.html) for an example on how to set up a Tooltip declaratively. Alternatively you can convert your code to add the images and their tooltips programmatically.